# Create SMS gateway in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sms, sms-gateway

I want to develop an SMS gateway in .NET, using PDU encoder/decoder classes. It's working fine for me, but the problem is receiving multipart SMS messages. I want to handle these messages with segmentation and reassembly, like Ozeki SMS gateway. Ozeki SMS gateway stores every multipart SMS in a file; I want to do the same thing.

If anyone has any experience in handling incoming multipart SMS messages, I would appreciate any explanations or examples of how to implement this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have some code that shows what you're doing / where you're having difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

These are called [Concatenated SMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS), information about sequence/total/current parts is available in the PDU UDH header of each incoming message part.

You would cache each incoming message then reassemble them when the final one is received.